# Need Jquery UI Autocomplete to parse an object instead of an array

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, object, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to attach an id to an employee name so I create an object instead of an array but only populate the auto complete field with names and not the id. jQuery Autocomplete sorce param parses an array. Can I parse an object.element? Here is some code (need more just ask). Is this possible?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'xml/employeeList.xml',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {alert('Could Not Retrieve Name List: '+xhr+', '+status+', '+error)},
    dataType: 'xml'
}).done(function(employees) {
    var empList = []; // array of objects
    $(employees).find('employeeList').children().each(function(index, element) {
        var $elm = $(this),
        first = $elm.find('first').text(),
        last = $elm.find('last').text(),
        lanID = $elm.find('lanID').text();
        empList.push({ // obj having label and value properties.
            value: lanID,
            label: first+' '+last
        });
    });
    console.log(empList);
    $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: empList
    });
});
```

After the user chooses a name from the auto complete, I need to send the employee lanID that was in the object with the chosen name back to a web service. in this example it does not assign the returned lanID as the id. The id ends up looking like this (  id="ui-id-345"  ). I need the id to be this (   id="whatever the returned lan id is"   )

After I select the name it then displays there LanID instead of the Name. Not the desired effect I was after. I still want it to show the name but assign the lanID as the id of the input or any attribute.

Comment: Why would you say this is a duplicate and then not provide a link to the other question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery ui autocomplete also accepts an array of objects having a *label* and *value* property. So if you want to include an *id* as well and search the values based on *name*, You can specify the name as the value  of *label* property and id as the value of value property.

Something along the following lines:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  url: 'xml/mockNameList.xml',
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {alert('Could Not Retrieve Name List: '+xhr+', '+status+', '+error)},
  dataType: 'XML'
}).done(function(employees) {
  var empList = []; // array of objects
  $(employees).find('employeeList').children().each(function(index, element) {
    var $elm = $(this),
    first = $elm.find('first').text(),
    last = $elm.find('last').text(),
    lanID = $elm.find('lanID').text();
    empList.push({ // obj having label and value properties.
      label: first+' '+last,
       value: lanID;
    });
  });
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: empList
  });
});
```

If you pass an array of objects having *label* and *value* properties, the search will happen based on the *label*, which is the name and whenever you select an item, the second argument (`ui`)passed to callback function will contain an *item* property whose value is the object corresponding to the item selected. So you can access the associated value, in your case the `id` like `ui.item.value`

---

Side note:

Note sure what you're trying to achieve by the following:

```
empList[index] = 'name: "'+first+' '+last+'",lanID: "'+lanID;
```

In your code `empList` is an object, not an array. It stores data as key value pairs, not based on indexes. The above will likely produce the object in the following form:

```
{
  "0": "name:Sir foo,lanID: 007",
  "1": "name:Sir bar',lanID: 008",
}
```

Which is pretty much useless for autocomplete as well as anything else, since *name*, *lanID* etc are part of a string and you can't access them via key name, instead you'll have to do string manipulation. Also, There's no guarantee in order while iterating over an object.

Comment: I need the lanID to be attached to the employees name

Comment: @DJERock That means you want this: *"0": "name:Sir foo,lanID: 007","* ..? then based on what you want to search..?

Comment: @DJERock I think you're missing the basics. If you do what I said, the search will happen based on the name, whenever you select an item, you'll get the selected object in the `ui` argument, you can access the value associated with it like `ui.item.value`. Other than accessing the associated value, is there a particular reason to concatenate the name with id..?

Comment: ok see my edit to my question

Comment: @DJERock What do you mean by *"The id ends up looking like this ( id="ui-id-345" ). I need the id to be this ( id="whatever the returned lan id is" )"* ..?  where is the code that attempts to retrieve the `id`..? Where does `id="ui-id-345"` comes from..? how does `employees` look like..? *"I still want it to show the name but assign the lanID as the id of the input or any attribute"*  - where is the code that attempts to add any attribute..?

Comment: <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-19" tabindex="-1">Employee Name Displayed</li> should look like this <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ewg" tabindex="-1">Erik Grosskurth</li>

Comment: i marked your answer right but it still doesn't do what I wanted it to or what I was asking if could happen

Comment: @DJERock If you think an answer was helpful just upvote it, don't accept it unless it answers the question. Your question already has 3 re-open votes including mine, If you can add more information, it's likely to receive 2 more and will be open (*try to address the question I've asked above...*)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64511/discussion-between-djerock-and-t-j).